# Connection Refused for Consul

Tags: spring-boot, connection, spring-cloud-consul

I am starting a Spring Boot Application with Consul.

I am getting the following error

```
2019-08-30 12:34:22.650 ERROR 23428 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8090 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect`
```

1. I changed the default port in `bootstrap.properties` file.
2. I also used another non-Consul Spring Boot Application and it worked fine for that use-case with same port.

Answer (score 0):

8090 is not the default port for Consul. You didn't say if your other successful app was on the same host or not, but make sure Consul is actually listening on that port with `netstat` or `ss`.

By default, Consul listens for API requests on port 8500.